# Delete rows with Sub Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't seem to get the SQL to work when using `LIKE`

```
DELETE FROM `customer_numbers` 
WHERE number NOT LIKE (SELECT number FROM number_part)%
```

Basically delete all the rows from `constomer_numbers` table if `number` does not contain in `number_part` table

Example:
customer_numbers.number = 0559354544 and number_part.number = 05593 - it shouldn't delete it.. However if 05593 does not contain in `customer_numbers.number` then delete row from customer_numbers table.. It should match first 5 digits from `number_part`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use not like with a list (in most databases, I'm pretty sure this is true in mysql).

Instead, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM `customer_numbers`
WHERE not exists (SELECT number FROM number_part
                  where customer_numbers.number like concat(number, '%')
                 )
```

Comment: If `customer_numbers.number` = 0559354544 and `number_part.number` = 05593 - it shouldn't delete it.. However if 05593 does not contain in 0559354544 then delete number from customer_numbers table.. It should match first 5 digits from  `number_part.number`

Comment: The inner subquery would return a number, when there is a match.  The "not exists" would preclude this from being updated.  Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is rather broken.  In at least two ways:

1. Your subquery returns multiple rows, but is in a place where it looks like you expect a single result.
2. You need your LIKE string to be quoted.

2 is probably easy to fix. Try:

```
... WHERE number LIKE CONCAT((SELECT ... LIMIT 1),'%');
```

1 is really your problem, though.  If you run your subselect as a single command, I expect you'll get multiple rows, right? How do you expect to treat a list of numbers (let's say, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`) as part of a LIKE string?

What I'm guessing you're hoping for is something like `LIKE '1%' OR LIKE '2%' OR LIKE '3%'...`, etc... No?

At any rate, if you can tell us more precisely what you're trying to do, we can probably help you solve your problem better.

As your question is worded, all I can say is:  **It doesn't work that way.**

Comment: Thanks for detailed response.. There are about 100 rows in `number_part` table (`number` could look like this: 1200, 1300, 1666, etc). In the `customer_numbers` table number could look like this 15343443455.  If 1200, 1300, 1666 number does not contain in 15343443455 then delete it.

Comment: MySQL uses `CONCAT` function, so `CONCAT((SELECT ... LIMIT 1), '%')`

Comment: If `customer_numbers.number` = 0559354544 and `number_part.number` = 05593 - it shouldn't delete it.. However if 05593 does not contain in 0559354544 then delete number from customer_numbers table.. It should match first 5 digits from  `number_part.number`

Answer (score 1):

You named your fields numbers but it seems like they are character values because of the leading 0s so I am going to assume they are character fields.

If your part number is always going to be 5 characters long then you can do the following:

```
DELETE FROM `customer_numbers` 
WHERE substring(number,1,5) NOT IN (SELECT number FROM number_part)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do a LIKE on a numerical field.
2. You can't do an equality on a sub-select that isn't DISTINCT.

You must use "IN".

```
DELETE FROM `customer_numbers` WHERE number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM number_part)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
DELETE FROM customer_numbers WHERE number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM number_part)
```